# show UITableView on tapping UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview, uitextfielddelegate

I want to show `UITableView` on tapping of `UITextView`.
 key board should not be shown.
 the problem is on tapping `UITextView` both `UITableView` and keyboard are shown. 
 I want only table view to be shown. I want to display data got from web service in `UITextView` which is not editable.on pressing edit button in navigation bar that time on tapping `UITextView` ,`UITableView` should be popped up and not keyboard.

My code is below:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{

if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}

-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{


[self.view endEditing:YES];

tableVw=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)];
tableVw.dataSource=self;
tableVw.delegate=self;


[self.view addSubview:tableVw];

 }
 -(void)viewDidLoad{

 [super viewDidLoad];

 txtVwDescription=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 270, 300,stringSize.height+10)];
 txtVwDescription.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
txtVwDescription.layer.cornerRadius=5;
txtVwDescription.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 green:0.662745 blue:0.662745 alpha:0.3];

[txtVwDescription setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0]];
txtVwDescription.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
[txtVwDescription setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
txtVwDescription.editable=NO;
txtVwDescription.delegate=self;
[self.view addSubview:txtVwDescription];
}

 -(void)edit{
 [txtVwDescription setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
 txtVwDescription.editable=NO;
 [txtVwDescription resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use UITextViewDelegate's `textViewShouldBeginEditing` method returning NO, and presenting there the UITableView. In such a way the keyboard should not be presented.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having to mess with textViewDelegate methods, I find it easier to simply disable editing for the textView and add a gesture recognizer to it like this:

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showTableView)];

    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:....];
    textView.editable = NO;
    [textView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

This way, no keyboard is shown and you don't have to mess around with navigation inside the delegate methods. All you need to do now is handle the tap with the method you provided the recognizer:

```
- (void)showTableView {
    // do stuff here
}
```

*EDIT:*

You might want to also consider using a UILabel instead of a UITextView if you are not planning on making it editable at all. You can implement the same gesture recognizer code as well, just add it to the label instead of the textView.

Comment: tableview is not coming in this approach

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` and `UITextView` classes has a property named `inputView` for displaying custom views instead of the default keyboards. The system shows whatever `UIView` descendant class you set to that property when the textfield/view becomes first responder. So simply add,

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
textView.inputView = self.myTableView; //this is your already initialised tableview
```